# How do I grep for this "^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@" from a file?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, grep

When I try to grep the below expression.

```
$ grep -A2 "IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready" log.txt
```

I get the result as -

```
date-time kern servname: []: info [   83.262033] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@date-time syslog servname syslog-ng[10831]: notice syslog-ng starting up; version='3.2.5'
date-time kern servname: []: info [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

Now the `@@@@` represents a system crash I believe, how can I grep for just '@^@'.

I tried `grep @^ file.txt` , `grep '@^' file.txt`, `grep '@.*@.*@' file.txt` and some other expressions without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the system is rebooted without files first being flushed it is possible that a file being written to will have the new size but the data has not yet been written to disk.

In such a case the hole in the file will contain NUL characters. (It is also possible to deliberately create files with holes in them without a restart, but I don't think that is applicable to your scenario.)

Some tools will display NUL characters as `^@` which is a placeholder for a single non-printable character and is totally different from a `^` followed by a `@`, which is why your grep command won't work.

With that information I was able to find an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/612336/326546) on a sister site. The solution suggested there is to use the following arguments for grep:

```
grep -Pa '\x00'
```

I have tested that this works for me. Notice that using `-P` or `-a` alone does not work, you do need both of them before `\x00` will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you only search for lines with "@^@" you can use `grep "\@\^\@" file.txt` (you have to escape the special chars).